# Write and Read functions of fstream on a linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, c++14, file-handling

I am pretty new to concept of file handling. I am trying to make a To-do list which keeps tracks of every modification in a file. I was unsure on how to implement this so I made a simple linked list and tried reading and writing it to a file but I failed.
Here's my code ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct node{
    int val;
    node *next = NULL;
};

void add(node *&head, int val){
    node *newPtr = new node;
    if(head==NULL){
        newPtr->val = val;
        head = newPtr;
    }
    else{
        newPtr->val = val;
        newPtr->next = head;
        head = newPtr;
    }
}

void print(node *head){
    node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=0){
        std::cout << (*temp).val << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    node *head = NULL;
    int val;
    std::ofstream filout;
    filout.open("data.txt",std::ios::out|std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);

    while(true){
        std::cin>>val;
        if(val==0)
            break;
        else{
            add(head,val);
            filout.write((char*)&head, sizeof(head));
        }
    }

    std::ifstream filin;
    filin.open("data.txt",std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    filin.read((char*)&head, sizeof(head));

    print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

What modifications should I be making to my code in order to get this correct ?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to execute the program for first time I can easily plug in some values and terminate the program by typing in 0 and everything's fine. But as soon as I run the program 2nd time, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error` in my print function at `std::cout` statement

Comment: "but I failed" How? What errors do you get? Btw you forgot to add c++03, c++17 and c++20 tags.

Comment: the first picture shows output, the second is a screenshot of some code...?!?

Comment: Please do not insert pictures! You can copy the output from your screens here and comment your source code with "fails here with..."

Comment: Okay wait let me modify things a bit :'D !

Comment: `filin.read((char*)&head, sizeof(head));` what is that string suppose to do?

Comment: It's supposed to read from a file ? I am pretty new to file handling so I am not completely sure

Comment: I see the idea now. try to delete file between program runnings. But the approach is kind of very bad idea. If you need to store structures in files look for serializers and deserializers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets get it step by step.

1. open file in *std::ios::out|std::ios::app|std::ios::binary* mode means:

   - **Output**
   - **Append**(open file and seek to the end)
   - **Binary**(something about line endings, better google it)
2. read data and store it

   - read value
   - add it to list
   - store in file(caution: `filout.write((char*)&head, sizeof(head));` stores an address of node in memory)
3. open file for read(without closing!) and read first value into *head*.

So, after second start you read **first** address of *head* node.

Some advises:

1. never do things involves casting data to char* in c++ without necessary
2. never store memory addresses in files(they useless or even danger to use after reallocation)
3. serialize you structures to store it(like [google/protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf))

Comment: Can you please edit my code as in to tell what exactly you're trying to show ? That would be really helpful to a beginner like me :') !

Comment: But that would delete my previous entries from my file !

Comment: you cant use them anyway =), or you need to store a values and read values back. You may use file streams like you do with `cin` and `cout`